# Four children are picked at random (with no replacement) from a family which includes exactly two boys. How large is the family?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Four children are picked at random (with no replacement) from a family which includes exactly two boys. The chance that neither boy is chosen is half the chance that both are chosen. How large is the family?

I am assuming here that female is the only other option and denote the number of females as $F$. On one hand, the number of opportunities that neither boy is chosen is given by ${F \choose 4}$. That is, we pick 4 children from the females.

On the other hand, we choose both boys and two girls. There are ${F \choose 2} $ ways of doing this.

> The chance that neither boy is chosen is half the chance that both are chosen.

sets us up with the following equation:

$${F \choose 4} = \frac{1}{2}{F \choose 2} \implies (F-2)(F-3) = 6 \implies  F = 5.$$

So the family has size 7. Is this correct? I would like to understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.